# Directive and scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code, ideally i should see

> parent: true

when I click the toggle

However, it doesn't work

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F38BkA)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click='isParentShown= !isParentShown' >Toggle</button>
  <div><span>Controller-isParentShown: {{isParentShown}}</span></div>
  <parent isShown='isParentShown'></parent>

</body>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []).directive('parent',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
                isShown: '='
        },
        template: '<span>Parent: {{isShown}}</span>'
    };
}).directive('child',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<span>Child: {{isChildShown}}</span>',
        scope: {
                isChildShown: '@'
        }
    };
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isParentShown = false;
});
```

Comment: The title of the question should be something about scope configuration in directives, the problem is not specific to nested directives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the casing of the attributes, if you define a isShown binding, it's expecting a `is-shown` or `is:shown` attribute. Here's the fixed plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UOigth

Comment: OMG, I am going to kill myself. What a stupid question ! Thanks for helping

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone ;)